# Given an array with numbers, how can I write a recursive function that finds indices in the array when 2 elements add up to a target?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is the prompt: Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.

Example:
Given nums = [2, 11, 15, 7], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

Here is my solution, but it doesn't seem to give the output I expected:

```js
var sumTarget = function(array, target) {
  var result = [];
  var copy = array.slice();
  var firstValue = array.shift();
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return result;
  }
  for (var i = copy.indexOf(firstValue) + 1; i < copy.length; i++) {
    if (firstValue + copy[i] === target) {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(result, [copy.indexOf(firstValue), i]);
    }
  }

  return sumTarget(array, target);
};
```

Comment: you mean supposedly it returns `[0, 3]` ??  Or more accurately, `[[0, 3]]`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/rqp93gpy/2/

```
function getIndexes(arr, target, offset) {
  var result = [], i;
  if (arr.length <= 1) return [];

  if (offset === undefined) offset = 0;

  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[0] + arr[i] === target) {
      result.push([offset, offset + i]);
    }
  }
  return result.concat(getIndexes(arr.slice(1), target, offset + 1));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getIndexes([2, 11, 15, 7, 6, 3, 4, 8, 9, 5, 7], 9),
                           null, 4));
```

output:

```
[
    [
        0,
        3
    ],
    [
        0,
        10
    ],
    [
        4,
        5
    ],
    [
        6,
        9
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answer which is based on a recursive method seems neater it's algorithm is brute and naturally expected to be somewhat less efficient in the performance. This approach is more functional and turns out to be 1.5 times faster on repl.it, 2.5 times faster on Opera, 8 times faster on Firefox and 25 times faster on Chrome console tests.

Roughly the logic is as follows;

1. Filter out the items greater than the target
2. Separate odd and even array items by establishing two separate hash table objects (LUT) in which we keep a unique copy of the valid array items as properties and each property has an array of it's indexes.
3. Perform two separate algorithms depending on target being odd or even

Let's see;

```js
var arr = [4,6,12,5,8,4,3,9,19,5,21,13,8,15,7,23,6,11,10,15,1,12,19,31,14,6,3,16],
    tar = 12;

function getIndexes(arr, target){
var   odds = {},
     evens = {},
   results = [],
makeResult = (a,b) => !!b ? a.forEach( e => b.forEach( f => results.push([e,f])))
                          : a.reduce((p,c,i) => {makeResult([p],a.slice(i)); return c});
arr.forEach((e,i) => e < target ? e%2 == 1 ?  !!odds[e] ?  odds[e].push(i) : ( odds[e] = [],  odds[e].push(i))
                                           : !!evens[e] ? evens[e].push(i) : (evens[e] = [], evens[e].push(i))
                                : false);
var oko = Object.keys(odds),
    oke = Object.keys(evens);
target%2 == 1 ? oko.length <= oke.length ? oko.forEach( e => evens[target-e] && makeResult( odds[e], evens[target-e]))
                                         : oke.forEach( e =>  odds[target-e] && makeResult(evens[e],  odds[target-e]))
              : (oko.forEach( e => (e <= target/2 &&  odds[target-e]) && (e < target/2 ? makeResult( odds[e],  odds[target-e])
                                                                                       : makeResult( odds[e]))),
                 oke.forEach( e => (e <= target/2 && evens[target-e]) && (e < target/2 ? makeResult(evens[e], evens[target-e])
                                                                                       : makeResult(evens[e]))));
return results;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getIndexes(arr, tar), 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

For those who would like recursion there is a tiny bit of recursion in the `makeResults` function.

As per performance comparison you may check https://repl.it/CIxd/1 vs https://repl.it/CIxr

Comment: do you need odd and even? can't you just build a hash table (a dictionary) mapping the number the original index, and say, if the target is 9, then when you see a 4, then check if 5 exist or not, and if yes, then that is one answer.  This is average case O(n).  So in the case of the target being 10 and there are many 5s, then all those can be answers... I suppose the worse case can be O(n^2), when you have an array of a million 5 in it, and the target is 10... but if the set of answers has about (n^2 / 2) items in it, won't the lower bound (the minimum steps) need to be O(n^2) anyway

Comment: I construct 2 hash tables one for odds and one for evens. They hold a unique presentation of each number with it's indexes for each occurrence. So if 4 appears in array 3 times at indices 5,15 and 17 Then evens hash table looks like {4:[5,15,17]} and so on... Odds and evens must be separated since depending on the target being odd or even your algorithm changes. For even target we will check both hash tables within itself up until the numbers half of the target.

Comment: So if target is 12 and evens contain [2,4,6,8,10] we don't need to check 8 and 10 since they have already been checked at while we check 2 and 4. While we will check for multiple occurrences of 6. If the target is odd this means it's a sum of an odd and even number. So this time we will take the shorter one of the odds or evens hash table and apply forEach on that. I suppose to increase efficiency the one thing you can do is to convert all array functions to their conventional for loop equivalents or you may adapt lodash. This will introduce around %300 performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

Vote for this:

```
    function sumTarget(ar, t) {
        var res = [];
        for (var i = 0, n = ar.length; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (ar[i] + ar[j] == t) {
                    res.push({ num1: i, val1: ar[i], num2: j, val2: ar[j] });
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    }
    sumTarget([2, 11, 15, 7], 9);
```

I hope it will help in your class ;)

Comment: i thought the question requires it to be recursive?